# Accessing ListView within an ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have an ItemsControl that is bound to a list of Objects.
I have an ItemTemplate set for the ItemsControl... and within the ItemTemplate I have a ListView, which I want to bind to another list of Objects.

How do I gain access to the ListView within the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate so that I can set it's DataContext to the second list of objects?

Here is an example of what I have:

```
                <ItemsControl x:Name="DealerShips" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White">
                                <ListView x:Name="CarTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=InStock}"></CheckBox>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

In my VB.NET code I can refer to my "DealerShips" ItemsControl to set the DataContext to a List(Of DealerShip) Objects. I can't figure out how to gain access to the "CarTypes" ListView so that I can set it's DataContext.

```
Public Class CarsWindow
    Private _listOfDealerShips As ObservableCollection(Of DealerShip)
    Private _listOfInventory As ObservableCollection(Of Car)

  Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        _listOfDealerShips = New ObservableCollection(Of DealerShip)
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("A"))
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("B"))
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("C"))

        _listOfInventory = New ObservableCollection(Of Cars)
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New Car("TypeX",True))
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New Car("TypeY",False))
        listOfDealerShips.Add(New Car("TypeZ",True))

        DealerShips.DataContext = _listOfDealerShips

        ' I cannot access CarTypes....
        'CarTypes.DataContext = listOfInventory 
  End Sub

  Private Class DealerShip
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Sub New
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
      Me.Name = name
    End Sub
  End Class

  Private Class Car
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property InStock As Boolean
    Public Sub New
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal isInStock As Boolean)
      Me.Name = name
      Me.InStock = isInStock 
    End Sub
  End Class
End Class
```

Thank you for your help!

-Frinny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that had both lists within it. 
Like this:

```
Public Class DealershipDetails
  Public Property ListOfDealerShips As ObservableCollection(Of DealerShip)
  Public Property ListOfInventory As ObservableCollection(Of Car)

  Public Sub New()
     ListOfDealerShips = New ObservableCollection(Of DealerShip)
     ListOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("A"))
     ListOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("B"))
     ListOfDealerShips.Add(New DealerShip("C"))

     ListOfInventory  = New ObservableCollection(Of Cars)
     ListOfInventory.Add(New Car("TypeX",True))
     ListOfInventory.Add(New Car("TypeY",False))
     ListOfInventory.Add(New Car("TypeZ",True))
  End Sub

End Class
```

That way I could bind the ItemsControl to an instance of the DealershipDetails class and selectively bind the controls within the ItemsControl to the appropriate lists.

While this approach works, my original question remains unanswered.
I do not know how to access a child control.

-Frinny

Answer (score 0):

Can you setup a viewmodel that contains your lists and make them public, set the cars window's DataContext to an instance of the viewmodel (maybe via DI), then change your listview in xaml to look like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="CarTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ListOfInventory, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```